# MySQL Case Error 1111 - Max(Column) Case Statement in SP

Tags: mysql, case

Summary: I am trying to add a Username to the db.username_table with a unique ID incremented by 1. However, I keep receiving an error 1111 related to my CASE statement. It should make the first User_ID 1, then all other new ones the max(user_id) +1. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Background: This is for my first MySQL project - I have some experience with MS SQL that may be hindering me here. I googled many references and streamlined my code as much as possible, but the aggregate for the counter returns a 1111 error with an IF or with a CASE statement.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE db.add_user
(
in new_username varchar(45)
)
begin

-- Set Counter ID
declare new_user_id int;
set new_user_id = if(max(db.username_table.User_ID) is null, 1, max(db.username_table.User_ID) + 1);

-- Add Username with Counter
insert into db.username_table (user_id, username)
values (new_user_id, new_username);

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Expected Result - Add a Username to the db.username_table with a unique ID incremented by 1.

Actual Result - Error 1111.

Comment: You are using  the funtion MAX  but not in SQL statements  .. so  the max of is used  improperly  .  you need  a select  for retrive a  MAX(db.username_table.User_ID.)...

Comment: Okay - so select case into?

Comment: i have posted an aswer  hope is useful ..but take a  look an autoincrement  too ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the funtion MAX but not in SQL statements .. so the max of is used improperly . you need a select for retrive a MAX(db.username_table.User_ID.)

```
  declare new_user_id int;
  select case when  
            max(ifnull(db.username_table.User_ID,0)) = 0 
                then 1 
                else max(db.username_table.User_ID) + 1 end 
  INTO new_user_id 
  from your_table ;
```

but could you simply need  an autoincrement column for User_id and avoid this SP

```
 CREATE TABLE your_table (
      User_ID  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      .... 
      )
```